# 404 after login in on adm panel (Magento 1.9.4.5)

Tags: admin-panel, 404-page, admin-login

Friends,

I'm always landing on a 404 page after trying to log in on my adm panel. I've realized that I'm being redirected to the following url after logging in:

https://my_domain/index.php//index/index/key/ae6593da750cfdb1b61aa5065268b88e/

The problem probably happens due to the **//index/index/** which shows up on the url but I don't know how to solve it or how to keep debugging? Any idea?

The login works just fine so that if I correct the url to https://my_domain/index.php/brtadm/ I'm able to access the adm panel with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very typical error. The best tutorial I have is in the link below:

https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-404-error-page-not-found-admin-url-magento-2/

Hope that helps.